# How to view values from stacked raster maps of a particular pixel at the same time (ArcGIS)

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.1

Re: ArcGIS v10.1

I have a stack of raster maps.  I would like to click on a pixel, and view ALL of the values for that particular pixel at the same time.  The only tool that I could find is the pixel inspector, which only displays the value for one map at a time.  I want to compare all values from my layered maps for this particular location at the same time.

Has anyone done this with ESRI software?

Comment: Are you looking to develop something to do this programmatically and if so which language(s) are you comfortable with?

Comment: I know some python, but I was hoping that ESRI had already developed something.  For example, a function of IDRISI software is a window that pops up when clicking a pixel of interest.  We have 20 layers, so the window has 20 rows listing the pixel value for each coincidence, which makes it easy to compare all 20 rasters.  The people we want to share our data with do not have IDRISI; they have ArcGIS.

Comment: I don't know of a built-in tool to do that but it would probably be pretty easy to do with a [Python add-in](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//014p00000025000000) (new at 10.1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Identify tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s500000010000000) does this -- it defaults to identifying from just one raster at a time, but if you change "Identify from:" from *Top-most layer* to *All layers*, you can see values from all rasters at that point.

Unlike pixel inspector, it does show only one point/cell at a time, but it can handle multiple layers in one click.

Comment: Good call, that is a very easy solution indeed. You could also set it to identify from Visible layers and just make your raster layers visible in case you have other layers in the map you don't want identified.

Comment: Indeed it is.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you want a permanent solution that can be incorporated into model builder or a script, I would recommend using [Extract Multi Values to Points (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000002s000000).  With this approach you define the sample points as a feature class and the tool appends the raster pixel values at each point to the point feature class's attribute table.  For example, the attached screenshot shows the results of tool for a stack of six raster layers.

[image]